# Onclick Event Bounce

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

http://www.lifechurch.org.uk/new-here/about/
http://www.lifechurch.org.uk/media/blog/

Im wanting to create a link effect similiar to this one

I found the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function(){
$(".target").effect( "bounce", 
{times:3}, 300 );
});
});​
```

Ive been told its using a library, any idea where i can source this from?

Thanks
Kirsty

***UPDATE***

I tried wrapping the link in the class which i want to bounce

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>jQuery example</title></head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="button">Click me</a>
<div class="target">I will bounce</div>
<div class="target">I will bounce too, since I have the same class name</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" id="button"><div class="target">Click me</div></a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // Notice the .on instead of .click, it's the new style for events
            // in jQuery and the e argument
            $("#button").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".target").effect( "bounce", { times : 3 }, 300);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And is it conflicting. Im not sure if u have seen the example of the above which i wish to recreate. But the H1 headers which are links are slightly "bouncing" or indenting which is the effect i wish to recreate on Wordpress Blog link headers

thanks

Comment: As for you updated code. You can only have ONE element with the same ID on any give page. So if you remove the first "click me" the last one will work.

Comment: hi fredrik, great stuff. Basically i just want all the H1 classes to do this. So i could code this in the CSS right then do it from there?

Comment: Is there a way to make it bounce down though ? Like the website seems to be doing

Comment: If you want all the h1 to bounce. Either add the `class="target"` to the or change the $('.target') to $('h1');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your HTML document: (Before the other script)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Notice the .on instead of .click, it's the new style for events
    // in jQuery and the e argument
    $("#button").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".target").effect( "bounce", { times : 3 }, 300);
    });
});​
```

Some sample HTML:

```
 <a href="#" id="button" class="target">Click me</a>
```

And here's a jsFiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fredrik/g8J3y/
..fredrik

Comment: Hi Frederick, This is to a button? I want this to be to a link like the text link on the website is?

Comment: Hi Fredrik, thanks for this. However i want the actual link to bounce and not the text below???

Comment: I updated the answer, just add the `class="target"` to what you want jumping

Answer (score 1):

This code is using JQuery ( http://www.jquery.com ), a very common JavaScript library.

The "bounce" effect is part of an optional add-on to JQuery named JQuery UI, see http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/

EDIT: Kirsty, if you want to learn about JavaScript and JQuery, http://www.codecademy.com has some great free interactive classes on both subjects.

Comment: Hi Gruse, thanks for these :) Would i change the DIV to for example H1 if i wanted on click H1 Headers to bounce?

Comment: Kirsty, if you're referencing Fredrik's code / the JSFiddle: Yes, as long as you keep the `class="target"` bit. Try it out! Also, I encourage you to read about how jQuery selectors work, that would make things like this much easier for you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

.effect is part of jquery-ui

download a custom min-js with only effects:

http://jqueryui.com/download/